# Update command in c# not updating database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-update

I have found a work around that solved this particular problem: the data from the database is loaded into one set of controls, and the update information is enetred into a separate set of controls.  Thanks for the comments; the application is working.

Trying to update a database row. I wrote the following code based on what I found on several fora/websites.  he code is not updating the database.

After trying anything to fix this error I have discovered the following: the database will update properly if the value of the @editFirstName is a literal, as in

```
      UpdateCmd.Parameters["@editFirstName"] = "George";
```

I also tried

```
  UpdateCmd.Parameters["@editFirstName"] = "'" + editFirstNameContent.Text + "'";
```

which did not work.

I also tried to put the TextBox data into a variable and use the variable:

```
   string firstNameValue = editFirstNameContent.Text;
   UpdateCmd.Parameters["@editFirstName"] = firstNameValue;
```

which did not work.

Therefore, the UPDATE command is apparently updating the databade.  However, apparently the Parameters.Value line is not reading the data in the TextBox, and so it is not updating with the changed value.

```
protected void editCustomerButton_Click(object Sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["proofreadThePlanetConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        string updateString = "UPDATE tblCustomerInfo SET customerID=@editCustomerID, customerFirstName=@editFirstName, customerLastName=@editLastName, customerEmail=@editEmail WHERE customerID=" + Request.QueryString["EID"];
        SqlCommand UpdateCmd = new SqlCommand(updateString, connection);
        UpdateCmd.Parameters.Add("@editCustomerID", SqlDbType.Int);
        UpdateCmd.Parameters["@editCustomerID"].Value = editCustomerIDContent.Text;
        UpdateCmd.Parameters.Add("@editFirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25);
        UpdateCmd.Parameters["@editFirstName"].Value = editFirstNameContent.Text;
        UpdateCmd.Parameters.Add("@editLastName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        UpdateCmd.Parameters["@editLastName"].Value = editLastNameContent.Text;
        UpdateCmd.Parameters.Add("@editEmail", SqlDbType.VarChar, 75);
        UpdateCmd.Parameters["@editEmail"].Value = editEmailContent.Text;
        UpdateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use all of those parameters then still have concat onto your command at the end.

Comment: As you add the updated values via Parameters.Add, you should also pass the QueryString parameter by Parameters.Add to avoid SQL injections. Why do you update customerID, which is probably your PK?

Comment: Do you get an error? Try putting a `try { ... } catch (Exception ex) ...` block around it - is there an exception? What datatype is `customerID` ?? If it should be a string, then you would need to put single quotes around it ! or better yet: **use a parameter!**

Comment: **WHAT** database and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by **many** database systems - **SQL** is **NOT** a database product......

Comment: Ash--I do this because this is exactly how example code is written on several different sources I found;

Comment: devio--how do you pass the queryString parameter by Parameters.Add...not a single example I looked at did it that way.  I update customerID because I was doing anything tot ry and get this to work (I've already spent four hours trying to do what one would think is a common and simple task).

Comment: marc_s--no, i do not get an error...I will put that in and see what I get, if anything.

Comment: marc_s: when I put the try/catch in, there appears to be no exception

Comment: marc_s: it appears to be MSSQL 10 (I think)--I created the database using SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R@ and SQL Express

Comment: the query strong value is now being passed as a parameter and the table is still not being updated

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how MS SQL Server handles auto-commit, but in case the auto-commit mode is not turned on, you'll need to commit your transaction manually (`UpdateCmd.Transaction.Commit`).

Comment: No - since there is no explicit transaction, the UPDATE statement will run in an implicit transaction and commit itself at the end...

Comment: So should I do this or not? If so, how do I do this?  All of the examples on MSDN are useless because I am nopt using a sqldatasource bound to a gridview, etc.

Comment: And if the UPDATE statement is running implicitly, why is it not updating the information?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Profiler comes with SQL Management Studio. Run this while executing your code to see what command is actually being executed.

Here's a tutorial on how to use the profiler.

http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Using_SQL_Server_Profiler

Answer (score 0):

I would check that

`Request.QueryString["EID"]`

does indeed contain a correct *customerId* value, as this could cause the statement to run but no data to be updated, if you are trying to update a row which does not exist.

To ensure the parameters values are being set correctly you could try the following format;

`command.Parameters.Add("@editCustomerID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = editCustomerIDContent.Text;`

As suggested by Ash, the best way to find out exactly what is happening would be to run Profiler against the database while the command is being executed (Note: This can have a performance impact and should be done on a Test/Dev system or out-of-hours)